# Xamarin Forms - WinPhone - Formatted text

Tags: html, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.winphone

My app needs to run on Android, iOS and WinPhone 8.1. It needs to have a page with a long text that include a lot of format:

bold
bullet list
link (http, mail, phone)

Because it has to run on all 3 platforms, I tried to create an HTML string in order to send it to a **WebView like this :**

```
MyWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource {Html = stringHtml };
```

So I can use `<b>` for bolds, `<ul>` for bullet lists, `<a>` for links.

Because I need also a custom font and specific size, in my html string there is a new style with all these the informations.
It works.... but with 2 problems on Windows Phone:

1. all the bullet list font size are really smaller than the rest of text
2. all the pages show a blank webview, but if I reload it (a lot of times) or wait 3/4 seconds then it shows the content

Any idea about these problems?

And if there's another solution different from WebView... it's welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms includes a *FormattedText* property in the Label (this guide should help you to understand it: [Xamarin.Forms FormattedText](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label/#Formatted_Text)). But there are some things you want to do that can't be done with it, and these are:

- FormattedText doesn't have links, but if I'm not mistaken, if you use links in a WebView, they will only work within that WebView, so the link will be open in the same space as your text.
- FormattedText doesn't have a bullet list. You can go around this problem adding the ASCII bullet character (in windows: Hold ALT and press the number 7) and some spaces to indent the paragraph.

The rest of what you want (bold, italic, color changes, etc.) FormattedText has.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: The links are needfull for me. And if you use "target="_blank" in tag, the website will be opened in a new browser window